# Populate UITableView from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm trying to make a table from the dictionary I have, but got an error. Since I just learning Swift I don't understand how to fix it. Could you help me please? Thank you for advance.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var DictionaryList = dictionary() {

        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()     
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DictionaryList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let entry = DictionaryList[indexPath.row]
        var key = Array<String>(self.dictionary.keys)[indexPath.row]
        var value = Array<String>(self.dictionary.values)[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = key
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value

        return cell
    }

    var dictionary: Dictionary = [
        "line1:" : "description",
        "line2:" : "description",
        "line3:" : "description",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var DictionaryList: Dictionary<String, String> = [:] {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.DictionaryList =  [
            "line1:":"description",
            "line2:":"description",
            "line3:":"description",
        ]
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DictionaryList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        var key = Array<String>(self.DictionaryList.keys)[indexPath.row]
        var value = Array<String>(self.DictionaryList.values)[indexPath.row]

        cell?.textLabel?.text = key
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = value

        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a table but without content (empty rows only)

Comment: something to do with cell height?

Answer (score 0):

This is never going to work. Dictionaries are unordered - there is no guarantee by a dictionary that `keys` is going to preserve the ordering each time it is called. There isn't even a guarantee that `values` is going to return the values in the same order that it returns the keys.

You will need to re-design your model to turn the dictionary into an ordered collection of some kind.